# Error One Drive al conectar el listener(3000) con MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aplicación-web

Estoy intentando crear mi primer proyecto utilizando NodeJs y MongoDB. Necesito saber como puedo quitar las rutas que esta guardada la terminar de Visual Studio Code, ya que cuando intento ejecutar el comando para tener el "Localhost:3000". Me indica un error con One Drive, ya eliminé One Drive de mi pc pero sigo teniendo las rutas en Visual Studio Code.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podria ayudar a solucionar este problema? Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor agrega la información del error que recibes o en caso de ser necesario, el proceso que seguiste. Estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [ask] para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes

Comment: ¿Porqué tienes tu proyecto en una carpeta de One Drive? Sería mucho más fácil ponerlo en una carpeta (por ejemplo `proyectos`) directamente en el directorio raíz de tu unidad. Por otro lado, dices: *cuando intento ejecutar el comando para tener el "Localhost:3000"* ¿Qué comando es ese? ¿Qué error te da? También dices: *ya eliminé One Drive de mi pc*, una cosa es eliminar la aplicación y otra cosa es que la carpeta `OneDrive - Universidad` siga existiendo. Como dije anteriormente, es más fácil crear una carpeta en el directorio raíz (por ejemplo: `C:\proyectos`) y guardar tus proyectos alli.